# Test if bash script was initiated from systemd

Tags: bash, systemd

As a Unix sysadmin, we experience issues with others (E.g. DBAs) starting/stopping services by interactively running scripts.  This means systemd has no knowledge of the state of a service. To prevent this, I insert a conditional in the scripts like this:

```
# The systemd unit creates a ORACLE_SYSTEMD_UNIT environment variable.  If this
# isn't set (i.e. Not running through systemd) then abort.
if [ "${ORACLE_SYSTEMD_UNIT:+set}" == "" ]; then
    logmsg "Not initiated through systemd.  Aborting"
    exit 2
fi
```

Can anyone suggest a cleaner method, or perhaps an Environment variable that is automatically set by the systemd unit activation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can check the command name of the parent process. In bash the process id of the parent process is stored in `$PPID`. The command name for a given pid can be obtained by `ps`. This only works if your script is running *directly* under `systemd`.

```
if [ "$(ps -o comm= $PPID)" != systemd ]; then
    echo "Not running under systemd"
fi
```

If you also want to check the parents of the parents and so on, iterate/recurse. The parent of any pid can be obtained by `ps` too.

```
runsUnderSystemd() {
    pid="${1-$$}"
    [ "$pid" = 0 ] && return 1
    [ "$(ps -o comm= "$pid")" = systemd ] ||
    runsUnderSystemd "$(ps -o ppid= "$pid" | tr -d ' ')"
}
if ! runsUnderSystemd; then
    echo "Not running under systemd"
fi
```

With `pstree` this can be shortend to

```
if ! pstree -s $PPID | grep -Fwq systemd; then
    echo "Not running under systemd"
fi
```

Alternatively, you can set an environment variable in your `.service` file for systemd ...

```
[Service]
Environment="STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=yes"
```

... which can then be checked in all children of the started service

```
if [ "$STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD" != yes ]; then
   echo "Not running under systemd"
fi
```

Please note that both approaches are just safeguards against mistakes. An attacker could fake or hide systemd in either way.

Comment: Thanks Socowi, I think your answer confirms that our current safeguard of setting and checking an Environment Variable is okay.  I'd hoped there may have been a more subtle solution that didn't involve tweaking the unit files but, it does work.

Comment: Well, there are other ways. I just thought that the environment variable would be the easiest. Anyways, I added even more alternative methods.